# App Widget state When background service get killed

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget which is being serviced by a Service in my code. Now when the application is forced stopped the service also stops. or due to some task killer app if my app service is killed

So now there is no one to update the widget and widget is acting like a zombie.

Now If I start the application activity the widget cannot be revived as I do not have the Id of the widget.

What is the best way to handle such situations?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to notify your service that the widget is ready to receive updates again? (passing over the widget Id). For example, in the onUpdate method of your WidgetProvider.

Comment: Say there is a widget which displays the running speed of the vehicle the phone is in using gps. So the widget needs to be updated every 20secs or so, In that case OnUpdate would be called at not less than 30mins. In between if the service crashes due to android / some task killer how to update the widget.

Comment: Maintain a list of configured widgets (and their widget id) in SharedPreferences. When your service starts, read the list and use accordingly.

Comment: :) well I did that eventually, but i was thinking it to be a bad hack. I actually have 3 entities a WakeAliveService in my code, a WidgetUpdateService and the AppWidgetProvider. WakeAliveService sends periodic broadcasts which are picked up by the WidgetUpdateService to update the widgets in a list stored in ApplicationClass. AppWidgetProvider updates the list with ids in OnUpdate / OnDelete. When the widget id is updated the list is saved back to prefs. When Application starts again the list is read. On a reboot this list is cleared. DO you think this is a right approach ?

Comment: It isn't a hack. Sometimes you need to store data relevant to a widget that will persist across app restarts or device reboots. SharedPreferences is ideal.

Comment: I thought this could have issues when the widget id is generated after reboot, so i coded to clear that prefrence. I guess on an update the widget would once get onUpdate so the code would populate the list of widgets again. Does it seems a valid approach?

Comment: The widget id is generated only when the widget is created. It remains the same across reboots.